# Subtracting arrays to get every difference

Tags: php, arrays

What I have

```
$array1 = [1,1,1];
$array2 = [1,1];
```

What I'm doing:

```
array_diff( $array1, $array2 );
```

What I expected:

```
array(1) { 1 }
```

What I got

```
array(0) { }
```

How do I subtract two arrays to get every discrepancy?

---

Edit:
My example was incomplete, sorry.

If we also have values like this:

```
$array1 = [1,1,2,1];
$array2 = [1,1,1,2];
```

I would expect

```
[1,1,2,1] - [1,1,1,2] = []
```

Comment: You are asking for the count difference?Can u elaborate

Comment: `array_diff` *does not* count duplicates. The only difference between array 1 and array 2 is the existence of a third 1. array_diff does not care about this and says they are the same. I need an array_diff that does this: `[1,1,1]-[1,1]=[1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_diff_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) is the right way to go here. But to get your expected result you just have to sort the array first with [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) where I compare the values with [`strcasecmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php).

So this should work for you:

```
<?php

    $array1 = [1,1,2,1];
    $array2 = [1,1,1,2];

    function caseCmpSort($a, $b){
        return strcasecmp($a, $b);  
    }

    usort($array1, "caseCmpSort");
    usort($array2, "caseCmpSort");

    $result = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);

    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array ( )
```

Answer (score 1):

**use array_diff_assoc**

```
$array1 = [1,1,1];
$array2 = [1,1];
print_r(array_diff_assoc( $array1, $array2)); // outputs Array ([2] => 1)
```

try it here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/43394cc048f8c9660219e4fa30386b53ce4adedb

Comment: I would also expect `[1,1,2,1] - [1,1,1,2] = []`. The result of this would be `[3=>2,4=>1]`.

Comment: correct with a small correction [2=>2,3=>1] !! check it http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c8cf3134ff63a475f1376927ef71636c46370fc7

Answer (score 0):

So you should check array key differences too. Have you tried array_diff_assoc()?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

From [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.
```

So, it is working as expected. I am not sure what exactly You want to achieve. You cloud try, it should give You expected result in **this** example.

```
$a = [1,1,1];
$b = [1,1];
print_r(array_diff_assoc($a,$b));
```

**Edit:** Well, simple sort should solve issue from Your comment. Nothe, that this will remove information of original indexes of elements.

```
$a = [1,1,2,1];
$b = [1,1,1,2,1];
sort($a);
sort($b);
print_r(array_diff_assoc($a,$b));
```

Comment: I would also expect `[1,1,2,1] - [1,1,1,2] = []`. The result of this would be `[3=>2,4=>1]`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$n = array(1,1,1);

$m = array(1,1);

$r = array_diff_assoc($n,$m);
var_dump($r);
?>
```